# Click On Specific Child Buttons Using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I'm looking for when I click on each image, navigate to a specific slider inside the slider element. The active slide have the class="active" so I just need to be able to target the specific button and add the class.

```
<div>
  <img src="#" id="image_slide_1">
  <img src="#" id="image_slide_2">
  <img src="#" id="image_slide_3">
  <img src="#" id="image_slide_4">
</div>

<div class="pf-slider-nav">
   <button type="button" class="active"></button> //Slide 1 Button
   <button type="button"></button>                //Slide 2 Button
   <button type="button"></button>                //Slide 3 Button
   <button type="button"></button>                //Slide 4 Button
</div>
```

I was trying something like:

```
$('#image_slide_4').on('click', function() {
  $('.pf-slider-nav button:nth-child(3)').addClass('active').click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use wild card for id on click event.

   ```
   $("[id^=image_slide]")
   ```

   `id` start with `image_slide`
2. When click on image , catch id, split and and get last value.

   ```
   var ind = $(this).attr('id').split('_').pop();
   ```
3. Delete all previous added class  on button and help of step 2 find index of button and add class .

   ```
   var _acBtn = $(".pf-slider-nav > button");
   _acBtn.removeClass("active"); //Remove previous active class
   _acBtn.eq(ind - 1).addClass("active"); // -1 because index start with 0
   ```

Working example:

```js
$("[id^=image_slide]").on("click", function() {
  var ind = $(this).attr('id').split('_').pop();
  var _acBtn = $(".pf-slider-nav > button");
  _acBtn.removeClass("active"); //Remove previous active class
  _acBtn.eq(ind - 1).addClass("active"); // -1 because index start with 0

});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="#" id="image_slide_1">
  <img src="#" id="image_slide_2">
  <img src="#" id="image_slide_3">
  <img src="#" id="image_slide_4">
</div>

<div class="pf-slider-nav">
  <button type="button" class="active"></button> //Slide 1 Button
  <button type="button"></button> //Slide 2 Button
  <button type="button"></button> //Slide 3 Button
  <button type="button"></button> //Slide 4 Button
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution in Vanilla JS:

```js
const btns=document.querySelectorAll("button");
document.querySelector("div")
        .querySelectorAll("img").forEach((el,i)=>el.onclick=()=>btns.forEach((b,j)=>b.classList.toggle("active",j==i)))
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="#" id="image_slide_1">
  <img src="#" id="image_slide_2">
  <img src="#" id="image_slide_3">
  <img src="#" id="image_slide_4">
</div>

<div class="pf-slider-nav">
  <button type="button" class="active">1</button> //Slide 1 Button
  <button type="button">2</button> //Slide 2 Button
  <button type="button">3</button> //Slide 3 Button
  <button type="button">4</button> //Slide 4 Button
</div>
```